# Split the string of a row of datatable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net. I am trying to split the data which is in datatable. I have a code sample like this:

```
 {      dt=objErrorLoggingDataAccess.GetErrorDetails(errorID);

        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "Message" };
        string error = dt.Rows[0]["Message"].ToString();
        string[] test = error.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string PageName = test[0].ToString();
        PageNameLabel.Text = PageName;

        stringSeparators=new string[] {HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()};
        error = dt.Rows[0]["Message"].ToString();
        test = error.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string Message = test[0].ToString();
        MessageLabel.Text = Message;}
```

in the datatable following data is there:

```
 {....ID.......Message.......................................................................................................................
 ....1........http://localhost:10489/images/CategoryIcon/images    Message :   File does not exist. UserName: naresh@naresh.com
 ....2........http://localhost:10489/images/CategoryIcon/images    Message : File does not exist. UserName: iswar@iswar.com}
```

My problem is: how can I split the Message and store in the label? I want

```
   {http://localhost:10489/images/CategoryIcon/images}
```

separately and UserName separately and the message separately. How can I do that? By executing the above code I am able to split

```
  { http://localhost:10489/images/CategoryIcon/images 
  }
```

only. How can I split the Message column and store in pageLabel, MessageLabel, UserNamelabel?

Comment: IF at all possible, change the structure of your datatable (and database) to normalize your results. Don't store multiple values in one column.

Comment: sir I have normalise the data before but the requirement is like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regular expression in this case. Because only by splitting this string looks a little bit to inflexible to me.

I tested your data example against this quick and dirty RegEx:

```
(?<id>\d+)\.*(?<url>\w+:\/\/[\w@][\w.:@]+\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*)\s*Message\s*:\s*(?<message>.*)UserName:\s*(?<username>([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3}))
```

It supports valid URLs and EMail patterns.

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(
      "(?<id>\\d+)\\.*(?<url>\\w+:\\/\\/[\\w@][\\w.:@]+\\/?[\\w\\.?"+
      "=%&=\\-@/$,]*)\\s*Message\\s*:\\s*(?<message>.*)UserName:\\s"+
      "*(?<username>([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1"+
      ",3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|"+
      "[0-9]{1,3}))",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );


// Capture the first Match, if any, in the InputText
Match m = regex.Match(InputText);

// Capture all Matches in the InputText
MatchCollection ms = regex.Matches(InputText);

// Test to see if there is a match in the InputText
bool IsMatch = regex.IsMatch(InputText);

// Get the names of all the named capture groups
// I included your fields as groups: id, url, message and username
string[] GroupNames = regex.GetGroupNames();
```

I don't know how often you need to call this code. Maybe you get in performance troubles if you have too much data. This regex is q&d - please adjust it to your needs.